# R - For each row in a data frame, how to check if at least one column is not NA?

Tags: r, missing-data

I have a data frame like this

```
col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4
12344 53445 34335 AAA
12545 56565 12123 AAB
NA    54556 32323 ABB
NA    NA    NA    NA
43434 65654 NA    ABA
```

I want to get rows with at least non-NA value, or put another way, rows with all NAs (row 5 in this case) should be removed. Can you give me some advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if your data frame is named dta:

```
dta[rowSums(!is.na(dta)) > 0, ]
```

This works by checking if each item `is.na`, taking the opposite `!`, taking the `rowSums`, finding those that are `> 0` and then using `[` to subset them.

Comment: it still works - rowSums are used on the boolean TRUE/FALSE as 1/0, not on the actual values